# Getting "directory not found" error when running parallel stage tests in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

When running a job in Jenkins, I intermittently get the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project my-tests: Fatal error compiling: directory not found: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test_master/target/test-classes -> [Help 1]
```

This job runs the stages in parallel with the following Jenkins code.

```
timestamps {
  node ('master') {
    withFolderProperties{
      nameSpace = "${env.namespace}"
    }
    println "Environment :: ${nameSpace}"
  }

  node('docker_test') {

    checkout scm
    stage ('Determining the tests to run') {
      if (stand) {
        List tests = [
          "test, Run Test"
        ]
        listTests.addAll(tests)
      }

      if (progress) {
        List tests = [
          "test_InProgress, Run Test - In Progress"
        ]
        listTests.addAll(tests)
      }

      if (standB) {
        List tests = [
          "test_B, Run Test B"
        ]
        listTests.addAll(tests)
      }

      if (progressB) {
        List tests = [
          "test_InProgress_B, Run Test B - In Progress"
        ]
        listTests.addAll(tests)
      }

    }
    stage ('Create build stages') {
      for (item in listTests) {
        String test = item.split(",")[0]
        String testDesc = item.split(",")[1]
        buildStages.put(item, stageConstructor(test, testDesc, nameSpace))
      }
    }

    stage ('Run Parallel Tests') {
      parallel(buildStages)
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas I can get around this? Would implementing a rety on the Jenkins code help? If so, how can I implement it?

Comment: Are you sure that your project is built correctly on all agents that execute the tests? It seems like your target-folder is not correctly built.

Comment: Yes, the issue occurs intermittently. I have the feeling there is a file/directory lock going on when the parallel jobs run. Was wondering if I can perhaps use a try/catch or a retry to wait until the lock is released?

Comment: Can you provide more code examples? Which parts of the test are executed parallely and on which agents? It is kinda hard to figure out the issue with the currently given.

Comment: Updated to add more code